# Memory management using IText in Java

Tags: itext

I am generating PDF's using IText and have noticed that the servers I am using seem to be running out of memory over time. I've turned off my feature to use IText and the servers seem fine - so I'm fairly certain there's something within my implementation of IText that is causing a memory leak. Here's my structure for IText:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
file = new File("/tmp/Hotel-Fax-" + voucher.getVoucherID() + ".pdf");

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
document.open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

//Some methods here which just create PDFPTables and add some text / images

cb.stroke();

document.close();

return file;
```

I am wondering if there is some way that my PdfWriter or PdfContentByte are holding on to memory even though I've closed the document, meaning that next time the code is called, it just creates new objects and the memory eventually runs out?

Comment: Have you tried to use a profiler?

Comment: Unless you have references to your pdfWriter or contentbyte outside the method, your garbage collector should handle it. What exactly are you trying to render?